# Changing drag and drop behaviour in Thunderbird (currently V68.x)

Tags: thunderbird, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for any Settings to changing Thunderbirds Drag&Drop behaviour in general or more specific when you drop the mail over in a folder e.g. via Windows Explorer (if you do that it will save the Emails as a eml-file, the file name will be the subject).

Except for a few Addons (which were insufficient) and a few settings in `about:config` (which were not relevant for drag and drop into the explorer or I misinterpreted them). I couldn't find anything that can be accessed via the settings or the config file.

Since the options in `about:config` are quite extensive I would like to make sure I didn't overlook a setting. I only found [this documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries) but there are still a lot of undocumented settings.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @harrymc essentially I'm trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203716/change-drag-and-drop-behaviour-from-thunderbird-into-windows-explorer), but for now I'm would be content with knowing if there are any settings at all concerning the d&d behaviour since I didn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such settings in Thunderbird, but it is probably possible
to do with some
[Thunderbird add-ons for Exporting](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/search/?q=export&appver=&platform=).

I have used in the past the add-on
[ImportExportTools](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/?src=search),
but now there exists a newer
[ImportExportTools NG](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/?src=search)
which may have more options.

If the tool cannot generate your format for the file-names,
you might write a `.bat` script that will rename the files.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Are you 100% sure that (currently) there are no settings for the drag&drop behaviour or is it that you just don't know of any? If you have a source that would be perfect! In regards to export: s far as I can see form the screenshots, the export tool is for exporting folders not individual mails (I want to drag&drop single mails).

Comment: Batch file won't "work", since the batch file doesn't know in which folder I dropped the mail (each gets dropped in a different folder). Well strictly speaking it will work but at the moment I don't see a way to make it much quicker then just renaming manually (the emails won't get dropped in a single folder but "all over" the file system). But thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: It might be possible to write a AutoHotKey script to detect and intercept such actions, but that is complicated.

Comment: Exactly what I thougt, that's why I (so far) decided to implement it via a Thunderbird plugin (ergo the post in stack overflow). Did you note the question in my first comment: Are you 100% sure that (currently) there are no settings for the drag&drop behaviour or is it that you just don't know of any? If you have a source that would be perfect!

Comment: No source, just that I didn't find any such option. It's hard to find a source that says that something *doesn't* exist. Well, we actually just created one such source right here.

Comment: ok, thanks, did you check the option in `about:config` as well or just the GUI-Settings? Did you figure out what the existing "drag"-settings apply to (e.g. `apz.drag.enabled`)? I couldn't find any documentation and with the tests I did so far changing the value doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: No, I didn't check config options that did not pertain to formatting. Boolean values are unlikely to help in dictating a format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Then I probably didn't write the question right, sorry. I would actually like to know if any of the drag and drop behaviour can be changed within the settings (including the config file `about:config`). If the very specific solution can not be achieved, an "incomplete solution" would work as well (then I can check where I can go from there). Any suggestion on how to better phrase the question would be greatly appreciated! PS. by the way the config file does not only hold boolean values

Comment: Yes I checked all configs that contained strings or their names were suggestive and found nothing. A little something that might help is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052733/165358) for an old-format add-on whose source can still be found on the [WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140723053014/http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/base/content/msgMail3PaneWindow.js).

Comment: thx again. it will be a good starting point for my own extension. As far as I understand the config settings that contain "drag" like `apz.drag.enabled` don't apply to drag&drop of messages either (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525956/disable-firefoxs-apz) and [here](http://codeverge.com/mozilla.dev.platform/testing-wanted-apz-scrollbar-dragging/2041159)).

Comment: Not really sure if I should "close" (accepting the answer) the question or if I should leave it "open" since both of us may have overlooked some relevant setting that is named differently. But I gave a +1 anyway thanks for your effort!